# Linear regression [R]: how to calculate multiple coefficients for the same predictor based on the occurrence of a categorical variable

Tags: r, linear-regression, gam

I have a forecasting with linear regression problem. In this problem the days of the week matter. At the moment I use:

```
lm.mod <- lm(y ~ x + monday + tuesday + thursday + friday + saturday + sunday, data=train)
```

Where y and x are continuous variables and the days of the week are dummy variables (they can be either 0 or 1). In this way the week dependence is given by different intercepts (the coefficients in front of the dummies). However, I would like to calculate a different coefficient for x for each day of the week.

I can do this operation when I use GAM (library: mgcv) inside the spline function, where "day" is a categorical variable containing the name of the day of the week

```
gam.mod <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x, bs='cs', by=day) + monday + tuesday + thursday + friday + saturday + sunday, data = train, method="REML", select=TRUE)
```

I show a few lines of the data frame train

```
Date        | y          | x          | day       | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2013-01-01  | 0.87604858 | 0.07339450 | Tuesday   | 0      | 1       | 0         |
2013-01-02  | 0.90190414 | 0.16513761 | Wednesday | 0      | 0       | 1         |
```

With mgcv I obtain a different spline for each day of the week (each value of the factor variable "day"), with a linear model I would like to obtain many coefficients for x as the number of values of factor variables.
Is it possible? Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it appears to me you are asking for the interaction between x and the week days?

I.e. simplified a bit, something like this:

```
# Toy data
n <- 100
train <- data.frame(replicate(5, rnorm(n)))
names(train) <- c("x", "y", "mon", "tue", "wed")

lm.mod <- lm(y ~ x*(mon + tue + wed), data=train)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid creating the binary terms yourself. In fact, the way the *mgcv* notation implies a spline by `day`, you ant to include `day` as a factor in the model, not all those separate terms.

So, the `gam` model would be:

```
gam(y ~ s(x, bs='cs', by=day) + day, data = train, method="REML", select=TRUE)
```

where `day` is a factor with levels `c('Monday','Tuesday', ....)`.

Then the linear model becomes:

```
lm(y ~ x * day, data = train)
```

You have to work a little harder to get the estimated means for each day; use `predict()` for the `gam()` model with `newdata` and one row per day and `type = 'terms'` and you can add the intercept to the `day` contribution (effect). For the `lm()` model you can most easily do this using the *multcomp* package.

You could also just drop the intercept (add `+ 0` to the model formula). There are other ways to potentially parameterise the model to model easily give you the estimates you may want.

That your models are even fitting is because R internally is dropping some effects; you can't fit an intercept and all those day terms because one of the separate day variables is linearly dependent on the intercept and thus cannot be uniquely identified.